# Fanfic where Clark Kent is befriended by Lex Luthor, who slowly nudges him into criminal acts

Tags: story-identification, superman, fan-fiction

While reading a very different fanfic involving Lex Luthor (a silly series involving Xander from *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* winding up as the character and completely wrecking continuity in the interest of having fun), I was suddenly reminded of reading a rather interesting fanfic several years (I think somewhere between 5-15?) where Clark, shortly after moving to Metropolis, is befriended by Lex. Lex encourages Clark to lighten up, and eventually gets him to commit a criminal act, I think smashing up a plate glass window with a concrete block and stealing a shirt. There was a strong homoerotic element to their friendship, which might have included Lex initiating a kiss on Clark. Clark has his powers, and is operating as Superman, with Lex offering an alternate perspective indicating that Superman is not a good thing. I don't recall if this was a matter of Superman being a tool of authority, his acts of heroics hampering humanity by not letting them solve their own problems, or something else.

The last bit I read (which might have been the final chapter) had a major twist.

> Lex doesn't exist (or maybe was dead before the events of the story) with Clark having been visualizing him, and his corrupting influence, as a way to escape the pressure of being Superman.

I want to say there were at least a dozen chapters, in English, and it may have been on fanfiction.net. I don't *think* it was based on *Smallville*, with Clark being definitely an adult from the start, and not knowing Lex prior to Metropolis.